# Flutter Third party library not supported

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

```
Note: E:\FlutterSDK\flutter_windows_2.10.1-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\device_info-2.0.3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\deviceinfo\DeviceInfoPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: E:\FlutterSDK\flutter_windows_2.10.1-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_share-2.0.0\android\src\main\java\com\example\fluttershare\FlutterSharePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: E:\FlutterSDK\flutter_windows_2.10.1-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_sign_in_android-5.2.5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlesignin\GoogleSignInPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: E:\FlutterSDK\flutter_windows_2.10.1-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_android-2.0.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\pathprovider\PathProviderPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: E:\FlutterSDK\flutter_windows_2.10.1-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\uni_links-0.5.1\android\src\main\java\name\avioli\unilinks\UniLinksPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
e: E:\FlutterSDK\flutter_windows_2.10.1-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\stripe_android-2.5.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\reactnativestripesdk\StripeSdkModule.kt: (110, 9): 'when' expression must be exhaustive, add necessary 'null' branch or 'else' branch instead
e: E:\FlutterSDK\flutter_windows_2.10.1-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\stripe_android-2.5.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\reactnativestripesdk\StripeSdkModule.kt: (127, 9): 'when' expression must be exhaustive, add necessary 'null' branch or 'else' branch instead
e: E:\FlutterSDK\flutter_windows_2.10.1-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\stripe_android-2.5.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\reactnativestripesdk\StripeSdkModule.kt: (145, 9): 'when' expression must be exhaustive, add necessary 'null' branch or 'else' branch instead
```

I have a created a project two yrs ago.Now i want to run this project but it's not supported deprecated library.

Comment: device_info is discountinued. You have to upgrade your project to make it working with necessory changes like upgrading library and some part of code as well. Use  latest  stable flutter version.